# Refer to either Semigroup or Monoid

Tags: haskell

I try to solve the exercises from the haskellbook and created following module:

```
module Exercises where

import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Monoid
import Test.QuickCheck

data Trivial = Trivial deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Semigroup Trivial where
  _ <> _ = Trivial

instance Monoid Trivial where
  mempty = Trivial
  mappend x y = x <> y
```

And the compiler complains:

```
file: 'file:///d%3A/haskell/chapter15/src/Exercises.hs'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Ambiguous occurrence `<>'
It could refer to either `Data.Semigroup.<>',
                         imported from `Data.Semigroup' at src\Exercises.hs:3:1-21
                      or `Data.Monoid.<>',
                         imported from `Data.Monoid' at src\Exercises.hs:4:1-18'
at: '14,19'
source: ''
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Would `mappend x y = Data.Monoid.<> x y` work?

Comment: Do you even need `Data.Monoid` imported? All it really brings into scope that isn't already in the Prelude is a bunch of newtypes and its version of `<>`.

Comment: Note that this annoying situation is temporary. In GHC 8.4 or 8.6 (don't remember which), `Semigroup` will be a superclass of `Monoid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you'd just

```
import Data.Monoid hiding ((<>))
```

(Or simply not import `Data.Monoid` at all – as Alec commented, the `Monoid` class itself is already exported from `Prelude` anyway.)
Then it's unambiguous that `x <> y` means `x Data.Semigroup.<> y`, because the `Data.Monoid` version is not in scope.

Alternatively, you can import one of the modules qualified, like

```
import qualified Data.Semigroup as SG
import Data.Monoid
import Test.QuickCheck

data Trivial = Trivial deriving (Eq, Show)

instance SG.Semigroup Trivial where
  _ <> _ = Trivial

instance Monoid Trivial where
  mempty = Trivial
  mappend x y = x SG.<> y
```